# Benefits of dynamically creating jQueryUI Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

In the past, I typically added my dialog as HTML as shown on the first example.

I never liked having to maintain both the HTML page and the JavaScript page, and am thinking of using either the second or third example (which one is more jQueryish?).

What are the pros and cons of both solutions?  For instance, will the second or third solution cause new DOM to be created, and if so will this cause any issues?  Or will they improve performance as more likely the JavaScript will be cached?  Or anything else???

```
$("#click1").click(function() {$("#dialog").dialog("open");});
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen    : false,
    modal       : true,
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'CANCEL',
            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    ]    
});

$("#click2").click(function() {$("<div title='mytitle2'>hello2</div>").dialog({
    modal       : true,
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'CANCEL',
            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    ]    
    });
});

$("#click3").click(function() {jQuery('<div/>', {title: 'my title3',text: 'hello3'}).dialog({
    modal       : true,
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'CANCEL',
            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    ]    
    })
});

<p id="click1">Click1</p>
<p id="click2">Click2</p>
<p id="click3">Click3</p>

<div id="dialog" title="my title1">
    hello1
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best case is to separate HTML and JS. What is the main reason that you dont like this solution?

What if you must send your templates to a designer team that have to restructure some DIVs? Most likely they have no-, or very little idea of Javascript, and dont know what to do.

**Pros example 1:**

- Structured files. Separating backbone (HTML) and UI functionalities (JS)
- **More performant**, because JS have not to create some DOM objects. They already are given in the HTML file, and JS has just to select it
- Designer team can use the html templates whitout knowledge of JS

**Contras Example 2&3**

- It have not the benefits of the explained example 1 pros

**Benefits between Examples 2&3**

- It could be that Example 3 is more performant. Because internally JS must split your written html string, into objects to create the new DOM object. But you should test it in a loop.

**Contras example 3**

- Writing jQuery instead of the alias $ all the time, results you longer code. Why not stay using $?

Comment: You convinced me.  One exception (which I didn't state in my original post) is a dialog which is used on many pages such as a "Are you sure you want to delete this record?".

Comment: Realized with example 1, you would have a div for the dialog as placeholder, in every page. If you dont like this because, this div is used rarely, you could realize temporary element with example 3, that exists only in the DOM when needed. **But dont forget** to remove the element after closing the dialog, otherwise you append the next creating temporary element on the previous one. Finally in this use-case, **example 1 would be still more performant, and needs also less JS coding** than example 3.